# Warning: ant Checkbox: value is not a valid prop, do you mean checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

While working with `Form` in **ant design v4**, I have difficulty with using `CheckBox` inside `Form.Item`.

```js
const [form] = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
        title: '',
        billable: false,
    })
}, []);

const onFieldsChange = (changedFields, allFields) => {
    console.log('onFieldsChange.changedFields => ', changedFields);
    console.log('onFieldsChange.allFields=> ', allFields);
}

return (
    <Form form={form} onFieldsChange={onFieldsChange}>
        <Form.Item label="title" name="title">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Billable" name="billable">
            <CheckBox />
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>
);
```

Above code gives me the following error:

> Warning: [ant:Checkbox] `value` is not a valid prop, do you mean `checked`?

How can I use `CheckBox` inside the `Form.Item` in **ant design v4**?

Comment: There is an example in the docs, [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [valuePropName](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item) for Checkbox form item:

```
<Form.Item label="Billable" name="billable" valuePropName="checked">
  <Checkbox />
</Form.Item>
```

Default value of `valuePropName` is `value` which is correct for input fields but not for a checkbox or switch.